# htaccess rewrite - pulling variable from dynamic host

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a set of mod-rewrite rules which look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} AAAexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.AAAexample.com/folder/AAA [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} BB-BBexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.BB-BBexample.com/folder/BB-BB [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} CCCCCexample.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.CCCCCexample.com/folder/CCCCC [R=301,L]
```

Essentially I have a set of domains matching `(PATTERN)example.com`, where `(PATTERN)` can contain any combination of letters and hyphens.

Is there a way to condense the above rules into a single set such that I Pull `PATTERN` as a dynamic variable into the final rewrite URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.%1%2/folder/%1 [R=301,L]
```